# 2006 Honda Pilot - Liquid Flowing/Pouring Noise

Tags: honda, noise, pilot

I have noticed recently that my 2006 Honda Pilot makes noises that sound like liquid flowing or being poured.

This occurs when braking while going down an incline when braking suddenly or when turning sharply.

The noise is at its loudest when I am going down an incline.

From the inside of the car it sounds like the noise is coming from the center console.

I don't see any noticeable leaking under the vehicle and there is no leaking inside the vehicle either.

Also no indicator lights are on in the vehicle.

I plan on bringing my vehicle to the service place as soon as possible to get this looked at, but I am curious if anyone has any thoughts or suggestions as to what the cause of the sound is and if this is an indicator of a potentially serious problem with the vehicle.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're soliciting thoughts & suggestions...

...it's possible that your Pilot, which has unibody construction, has picked up some water inside its integrated frame, and you actually hear that water moving around inside the frame. I've had that happen before - in my case, a plastic plug was missing and when I drove through a large puddle the frame would take on a surprising amount of water from the splash (I was young then, and knew no moderation in my driving style). It usually took several weeks of hot dry weather before the water evaporated back out of the frame.

Comment: I've had that with my Land Rover - a panicked 'what's that noise', followed by the sudden realisations that it's the previous puddle flowing back out of the sills!

Answer (score 1):

Two common sources of water rushing noises are water in one or more of the doors and air in the cooling system causing gurgling in the heater core.
For the doors, check the bottom edge of all doors including the lift gate. There are small rubber drains that allow water to drain when it rains. If they become clogged the doors begin to fill with water and can make noise. Use a very small screwdriver or stick to poke through the drains and unclog them. I have personally seen up to a gallon or more drain out of doors.

For the cooling system, make sure your radiator is completely full as well as your overflow tank. If not, fill the radiator completely with a cold engine and the overflow to the full line. Park the vehicle with the front on a steep incline. With the vehicle in park Rev the engine to about 1200 RPMs with the A/C off. Wait for the cooling fans to cycle one full time. This should allow the thermostat to open and any air that may be trapped in the heater core to make it to the radiator and hopefully be purged to the overflow tank.

Hope this helps!
~Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar water sloshing/pouring sound in my civic and I have been advised by Honda technician that it may be due to air in the radiator and related pipes caused due to leakage of coolant from radiator. once my coolant reached to the lowest level and then I refilled it. so the advise given by the technician seems to be logical